# Can't install react app using npx create-react-app. Node The engine "node" is incompatible with this module

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I tried to install a react app using npx create-react-app name. But I ran into this error:
`css-loader@1.0.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">= 6.9.0 <7.0.0 || >= 8.9.0". Got "8.7.0"`

I already updated my homebrew and node, when I ask for my node version it says 11.2.0 so I don't really now what I am doing wrong.

[image]

Comment: Solved it, just had to let nvm use the latest version of node

Answer (score 0):

You can also just install the latest version of node from their website

https://nodejs.org/en/download/

And everything should work fine

Comment: you still have to make sure nvm is using the latest version of node